# Problems with fisher.test

Tags: r, statistics

I get an error message if I try to use `fisher.test`:

```r
fisher.test(carprices$insurance_symboling, carprices$weight)
```

> Error in fisher.test(carprices$insurance_symboling, carprices$weight) : FEXACT error 6 (f5xact). LDKEY=427 is too small for this problem: kval=317844542. Try increasing the size of the workspace.

Comment: Could we please have a [mcve]? Did you look at any of the existing answers on this topic, e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17052639/fisher-test-error-ldstp-is-too-small/17054348#17054348 ?

Comment: The `fisher.test` is applicable only to count/frequency data. Are both `insurance_symboling` and `weight` factors? The error message suggests that the crosstabulation of these two variables produces a very large table.

Comment: Weight is a metric factor and insurance_symboling an ordinal factor. The dataset has 205 entries